# Removing 'prettify' / 'collapsing characters' in PhpStorm

Tags: formatting, phpstorm

How do I stop PhpStorm from collapsing my characters, as can be seen here:

[image: html-comment-arrows]

As can be seen, then the comment-arrows are 'nice and beautiful' (bwwadr!!).

I've read through the entire preferences-sections and Google for about 30-45 minutes. ... But everything about 'collapsing' shows results about 'folding code' or 'collapsing code'. And every time I Googled anything about 'removing space between characters', then I find pages about controlling tabs'n'spaces.

This is driving me up the wall...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It called **font ligatures** (the only thing I'm aware of that will do such thing) -- you must have it enabled.

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Font --> Enable font ligatures`

[image]

A bit info on what that is:

- https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/06/webstorm-2016-2-eap-162-646/
- https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/07/intellij-idea-2016-2-is-here/
- https://youtu.be/Bjq-A4LCU9M?t=23m37s